# jQuery check if an image inside a div is true or false

Tags: jquery

**My HTML**

```
<div class="block_right_2 relative">
  <div class="block_right_2_content">
    <div align="center"> <a href="#"> <img src="/images/imageName1.png" > </a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block_right_2_btn_link_left">
    <p><a href="/article/newsflash.html">Find out more </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Question**

This imageName1.png is a random image on my website and it changes everytime I refresh the page. The other image names are `imageName2.png`, `imageName3.png` etc. What I want to do is, use jquery to check `if image = imageName2.png` then change the link `Find out more` to `More info here`. Thanks.

Im not sure how to use `.replace` or a more suitable method check this. Thanks.

Comment: the link would be `/article/newsflash.html`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then below should do the trick.

```
if ($('.block_right_2_content').find('img')[0].src.indexOf('imageName2.png') >= 0) {
   $('.block_right_2_btn_link_left').find('a').text('More Info here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
$('img[src$="imageName1.png"]').closest('.block_right_2_content')
                                .next().find('a').text('More info here');
```

Uses the `Attribute Ends with` selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/GudSq/1